# css style sheet location ubuntu linux

Tags: php, html, css, linux, ubuntu

Rather silly question  I suppose. I am trying to add web template to my PHP file in Ubuntu, I have defined the link and have stored the `form.css` file in same location where my other PHP files are e.g `var/www/html/web` but for some reason I cant show the template in my webpage. see [pic attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpH1M.png) and thanks for help.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/a4e256ed67403c6ad5d43937ed48a77b?family=Core+Sans+N+W01+35+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" type="text/css">

<div class="body-content">
  <div class="module">
```

Comment: When you say you can't show the template, do you mean your CSS is not loading ?

Comment: yes thats right....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I would check for this:

- The permissions on the form.css file. Perhaps the webserver does not have permission to access it? if so run `chmod 644 form.css`
- The case of the letters, Maybe it is named Form.css and not form.css Unlike Windows Linux has case sensitive file names
- Maybe it can access it but the code in the file is unreadable (bad code). To test this create another file which does something you know will work and add that to your project. Or try accessing it directly by typing  `localhost/path/to/form.css`  into your web browser and see if it can access it.